# Jira: Project vs Component for multiple teams

Tags: components, project, jira

In my department, we have 8 Scrum teams where every team has their own products, releases and backlogs. But we also have some shared components and help each other when needed. So, which approach do you think is best for us? What are the benefits and drawbacks? Please share your experience.

- A) Project per team: Each team will have its own Jira project and prefix.
- B) Component per team: There will be one Jira project with components per each team. Scrum boards will have a filter like "component=A".

Some factors to consider:

- Team should be able to see each other's boards.
- Occasionally, a member from Team A should be able to create an issue and possible work on an issue for Team B.
- We should be able to generate department-wide reports as well as team-specific ones.
- Teams and Scrum Masters should have full control on their activities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well i think B is the best choice

benefits

- easy user management - when all developers are in the same project you need to define your roles once.
- when you make several boards to the same projects its shared automaticly with no permission problems.
- Department wide reports can be issued by the report tab in the project area. and not be assambled roughly.
- Team members that will want to create an issue for another team will simply create an issue and specify a component according to the team.
- if you use pre commit hooks to verify that smart commit was usedm you only need to search for that specific prefix.

now the drawbacks

- The team leaders may ruin each other configurations hance they all have administration permissions on the project.
- if a developer will forget to specify its component the task will not apear on any board since you edit your smart filters to Component='A'.
- Many stats in the projects and complex workflow scheme.

Hope I helped :)